# How do I plot a FreqDist of a column in my DataFrame?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I've been trying to write a FreqDist to analyze text data that I have preprocessed (stopwords removed, tokenized etc.), to get a sense of what's the text data mainly about. My first question is that, is my approach on the right track? And my second question is that I've tried to plot a FreqDist plot but it returned an error

`unhashable type: 'list'`

My code is as follow:

`from nltk.probability import FreqDist`

`df={'text':[['like','play','tennis','football'], ['favorite','baseball','basketball']]}`

`freq = FreqDist(df['text'])`

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

FreqDist input could be a list, not list of lists. that is why you get error.If you write :

```
freq = FreqDist(df['text'][0])
```

you will get first row freqs. if you want to get all data freqs, first you should concatenate records

```
merged_list = []
for lst in df['text']:
    merged_list += lst
freq = FreqDist(merged_list)
freq
```